# Error 403 message seen during API testing in DUO even though valid credentials were provided. Does wrong integration type mean i need a new key?

Tags: api, security, oauth-2.0, postman, duosecurity

I used the following API in postman with integration key, client secret from the Admin API application but no luck.
`GET: https://api-123abc.duosecurity.com/auth/v2/check`
Furthermore,

1. I used basic auth for authorization
2. Integration key for username  and created the password via
   https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output (used
   integration key for string and client secret from the duo UI)

I used the following headers:

```
Authorization:Basic
Integration-key:Secret-key
Date:Fri, 20 May 2022 02:26:39 +0000
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Besides this I used the code

```
btoa('integration key:secret key')
```

to generate authentication code but it still gives the following error

```
{
    "code": 40301,
    "message": "Access forbidden",
    "message_detail": "Wrong integration type for this API.",
    "stat": "FAIL"
}
```

Comment: Can you update response status code.

Comment: Updated @prasanth. Can you help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Add Postman PreRequest script
- update/replace integration and secret keys in below script
- follow [docs](https://duo.com/docs/authapi#api-details)

```js
const cannon = [
    new Date().toUTCString(),
    pm.request.method,
    pm.request.url.host.join('.'),
    '/'+pm.request.url.path.join('/'),
];


if (pm.request.body.urlencoded){
    cannon.push(pm.request.body.urlencoded);
}

function hmacSign(cannon, integrationKey, secretKey){
    const message = cannon.join("\n");
    console.log(message);
    var hmac =  CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, secretKey)
    return btoa(`${integrationKey}:${hmac}`)
}



const sign = hmacSign(cannon, "DIWJ8X6AEYOR5OMC6TQ1", "Zh5eGmUq9zpfQnyUIu5OL9iWoMMv5ZNmk3zLJ4Ep")

pm.request.headers.add({
    key: "authorization",
    value: sign
});
```

[image]

Comment: Now I am facing an issue of 401. Could you please provide me the headers which you have used and the url of your get request. I can also see from the above screenshot that your status is 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Those are sample keys. not actual keys. i'm not registered for dua security.